# Getting Array of struct from IntPtr

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling, intptr

I have some struct like this

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public int field1;
    public int field2;
    public int field3;
}
```

and I have pointer to array of this struct.
So, I need to get array from this pointer.
I'm tried to using Marshal.PtrToStructure, but i had memory reading error.
This is my methode:

```
public MyStruct[] GetArrayOfStruct(IntPtr pointerToStruct, int length)
{
    var sizeInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TCnt));
    MyStruct[] output = new MyStruct[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        IntPtr p = new IntPtr((pointerToStruct.ToInt32() + i * sizeInBytes));

        output[i] = (MyStruct)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, typeof(MyStruct));
    }

    return output;
}
```

So, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: why is `sizeInBytes=Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TCnt));` instead of being `sizeInBytes=Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct));` ?

Answer (score 17):

This function worked for me, assuming that the **size of the struct is fixed**:

```
public static void MarshalUnmananagedArray2Struct<T>(IntPtr unmanagedArray, int length, out T[] mangagedArray)
{
    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    mangagedArray = new T[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        IntPtr ins = new IntPtr(unmanagedArray.ToInt64() + i * size);
        mangagedArray[i] = Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(ins);
    }
 }
```

Comment: `ToInt64()` did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Two problems.  You use TCnt instead of MyStruct in the Marshal.SizeOf() call.  Your IntPtr arithmetic cannot work on a 64-bit machine, you must use IntPtr.ToInt64() or cast to (long).

Just getting the wrong IntPtr or length is certainly a possibility too of course.  Use Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory 1 and put "pointerToStruct" in the Address box for basic verification.

Comment: TCnt is some kind of misprint. Using ntPtr.ToInt64() gives same result

Comment: I think the more common term for it is "bug".  Anyhoo, enough to get you going I imagine.  The Memory window is your ultimate debugging tool.

Comment: FYI, C# 4 introduced IntPtr.{Add,Subtract} to make pointer arithmetic less error-prone.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5170453/603828

Answer (score 2):

Structs in C and C# are not the same thing. One of the differences is that in C# you have to explicitly demand that your struct should be sequentially laid out. If you didn't write
`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` or `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` attribute to your structure I don't believe that you can manage it in this way. Microsoft states that `PtrToStructure` is to be used to convert structures from unmanaged to managed memory

You should test if adding this attributes to your struct helps, If it doesn't yet help try allocating memory with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr)` and use `Marshal.Copy` to init your structure and then try using `PtrToStructure`. If this works then you can't use `PtrToStructure` with managed memory