# How to convert the IntPtr to an array?

Tags: c#

How to convert the `IntPtr` to an array. Actually I called the function from unmanaged dll. It returns `IntPtr`. Now I need to convert it to an array. Please any one give an idea.Code snippet is below.

```
Unmanaged function declared

[DllImport("NLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern unsafe IntPtr N_AllocPt1dArray(NL_INDEX n, ref stacks S);
```

Calling the function

```
void Function1()
{
     IntPtr PPtr=N_AllocPt1dArray(n, ref S);
}
```

Now I need to convert `PPtr` to an array(array is `demo[]`).where demo is defined by

```
public unsafe struct demo 
{            
    public int x ;
    public int y ;
    public int z ;
}demo DEMO;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Array of struct from IntPtr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747112/getting-array-of-struct-from-intptr)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
array[0] = (demo)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(PPtr , typeof(demo));
```

UPDATE :

Solution 2 of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/299085/Marshal-structures-passed-as-pointers-to-functions) [page](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/299085/Marshal-structures-passed-as-pointers-to-functions) is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for answering.But now i got array structure.How to convert it to array demo[] array.

Comment: Please refer to the link provided in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

It depends of what type of data you are pointing to, the next code get an array of strings from an IntPtr:

nstring is the number of elements you expect to get.

You can modify the code to satisfy your needs, but this can give you an idea of how to retrive data from an IntPtr in an unmaganed block code.

```
private string[] ConvertIntPtrToStringArray(IntPtr p, int nstring)
{
    //Marshal.ptr
    string[] s = new string[nstring];
    char[] word;
    int i, j, size;

    unsafe
    {   
        byte** str = (byte**)p.ToPointer();

        i = 0;
        while (i < nstring)
        {
            j = 0;
            while (str[i][j] != 0)
                j++;
            size = j;
            word = new char[size];
            j = 0;
            while (str[i][j] != 0)
            {
                word[j] = (char)str[i][j];
                j++;
            }
            s[i] = new string(word);

            i++;
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

cheers, 
Kevin