# Access Violation for Marshalling Ptr To Struct

Tags: c#, c++, c, struct, marshalling

I have the following structs defined in my c dll:

```
typedef struct {
    char Name[10];
    char Flag[10];
} CountryData;

typedef struct {
    int NumElements;
    TrackData Elements[1000];
} CountryArray;
```

Which is exposed like so:

```
__declspec( dllexport ) CountryArray* _cdecl GetAllCountries()
{
    CountryArray fakedata;
    CountryData fakecountry = CountryData();
    strcpy_s(fakecountry.Name, "TEST");
    strcpy_s(fakecountry.Flag, "TEST");
    fakedata.Elements[0] = faketrack;
    fakedata.NumElements = 1;
    return new CountryArray(fakedata);
}
```

Now in c# I have these structs defined:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct COUNTRY
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
        public string Name;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
        public string Flag;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct COUNTRY_ARRAY
    {
        public int NumElements;
        public IntPtr Elements;
    }
```

And I access it through this import:

```
    [DllImport("Countries.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?GetAllCountries@@YAPAUCountryArray@@XZ")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetAllCountries();
```

And finally I attempt to marshal the data like so:

```
IntPtr countryPtr = Natives.GetAllCountries();
Natives.COUNTRY_ARRAY countries = (Natives.COUNTRY_ARRAY)Marshal.PtrToStructure(countryPtr, typeof(Natives.COUNTRY_ARRAY));
for (int i = 0; i < countries.NumElements; i++)
{
    IntPtr iptr = (IntPtr)(countries.Elements.ToInt32() + (i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Natives.COUNTRY))));
    try
    {
        //fails here
        Natives.COUNTRY country = (Natives.COUNTRY)Marshal.PtrToStructure(iptr, typeof(Natives.COUNTRY));                    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }                
}
```

The marshalling of the country is where I receive this error:

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructureHelper(IntPtr ptr, Object structure, Boolean allowValueClasses)
```

I've tried modifying the size of the COUNTRY struct and changing the charset but still get this error.  I'm completely stuck, what can be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your issue is that you're treating the value of `Elements` like a pointer, when in fact it's the data of the first element of the array. In your test case, this gives `Elements` a value of `0x54455354` on a 32-bit system and `0x5445535400000000` on a 64-bit system ("TEST" in hex). You are offsetting that pointer. Instead, you want to get the pointer to the `Elements` field, which can be done like so:

```
IntPtr elementsOffset = Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(COUNTRY_ARRAY), "Elements");
```

You would then take the pointer you get back from the function and add the offset to it when calculating the location of each element.

Also, you should [always use IntPtr's `ToInt64()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1866268/1122135). It's a tad bit slower on 32-bit systems but avoids the terrible edge case of truncating memory addresses in 64-bit systems.

Additionally, the name mangling on your entry point leads me to believe that this is being compiled with a C++ compiler. Your bindings will fail if you compile with a different compiler or even a different version of the same compiler. What you should do is export these methods as C functions so that they don't get mangled. To do this, wrap the methods you're exporting in an `extern "C" { ... }` block.

Also, you can avoid this issue entirely by letting the struct do the work for you:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct COUNTRY_ARRAY
{
    public int NumElements;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 1000)]
    public COUNTRY[] Elements;
}
```