# Using Vertex Arrays with OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I know it's probably better to use VBO instead, but I have personal reasons to use Vertex Arrays (beside my curiosity)

In C++, here the vertex arrays is used:

```
// "vertices" is an array of Vertex Struct
const char* data = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(vertices);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), data + 0));
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), data + 8));
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), data + 16));

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vertexCount);
```

the pointer passed and worked nicely in C++, however, I can't make it work in C# with OpenTK. I followed the [official documentation](http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics/geometry/vertex-arrays) and ended up with this codes:

```
Vertex[] vertices =  // .. Fill some vertex here

unsafe
{
    fixed (Vertex* data = vertices)
    {
        GL.VertexPointer(2, VertexPointerType.Float, Vertex.Stride, new IntPtr(data + 0));
        GL.TexCoordPointer(2, TexCoordPointerType.Float, Vertex.Stride, new IntPtr(data + 8));
        GL.ColorPointer(4, ColorPointerType.Float, Vertex.Stride, new IntPtr(data + 16));

        // Draw the Vertices
        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Quads,
            0,
            vertices.length);

        GL.Finish();    // Force OpenGL to finish rendering while the arrays are still pinned.
    }
}
```

What I got is only blank white, nothing displayed.

I tried to use same vertices with my VBO implementation also similar vertices pointers code, it's working properly, so I think its not setup code fault and I'm sure `Vertex.Stride` returning valid stride of `Vertex` struct.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Considering your proven c++ skills, it's arguably easier to do it in c++/CLI (including a WinForm window) and use OpenGL proper just in case there is something funky going on with opentk.  Particularly when you are using _pointers_

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to stick with C# in this situation..

Comment: Try to stick to example grammar: 1: `Vertex* data = vertices` 2: `GL.VertexPoi...  stride, data);` `GL.ColorPoi...  stride, data + 16);`

Comment: Still not working, I can use `Vertex* data = vertices;` but i can't pass the `data` directly, the parameter expect integer / `IntPtr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unsafe` route didn't work because `new IntPtr(data + 8)` will point 8 vertices ahead instead of pointing 8 bytes ahead. You can fix this by using `IntPtr.Add` method:

```
fixed (Vertex* data = vertices)
{
  var stride = Marshal.SizeOf<Vertex>();
  GL.VertexPointer(2, VertexPointerType.Float, stride, 
      new IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(data), 0));
  GL.TexCoordPointer(2, TexCoordPointerType.Float, stride, 
      new IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(data), 8));
  GL.ColorPointer(4, ColorPointerType.Float, stride,
      new IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(data), 16));

  GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Quads, 0, vertices.Length);

  GL.Finish();  
}
```

Or you can make it less error prone by grabbing the relevant pointers directly:

```
fixed (void* posPtr = &vertices[0].x, texPtr = &vertices[0].u, colorPtr = &vertices[0].r)
{
  var stride = Marshal.SizeOf<Vertex>();
  GL.VertexPointer(2, VertexPointerType.Float, stride, 
      new IntPtr(posPtr));
  GL.TexCoordPointer(2, TexCoordPointerType.Float, stride, 
      new IntPtr(texPtr))
  GL.ColorPointer(4, ColorPointerType.Float, stride,
      new IntPtr(colorPtr))

  GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Quads, 0, vertices.Length);

  GL.Finish();  
}
```

I'll assume Vertex is defined as, or similar to:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct Vertex
{
   public float x, y;
   public float u, v;
   public float r, g, b, a;
};
```

EDIT:

1. `StructLayout` `LayoutKind.Sequential` attribute explicitly tells the compiler NOT to rearrange the order of variables in the memory.

   **NB.** This is not strictly necessary in this case because according to MSDN `LayoutKind.Sequential` is default behavior for `struct`s (value types).
2. `Pack = 1` additionally tells the compiler to pack the variables in memory tightly, without leaving in any gaps. By default compiler tries to align memory on 4 (or 8) byte boundary.

   **NB.** Again this is not necessary for the given `Vertex` struct as all variables are perfectly aligned on 4 byte boundaries and there are no gaps in between.

The reason why I still keep the `StructLayout` attribute in this case, even if it works perfectly without it, is to be crystal clear and explicit about  the expected memory layout of the `Vertex` structure as it is important in cases like these.

---

EDIT2: works with generics too

```
public struct Vertex
{        
    public Vector2<float> Pos;        
    public Vector2<float> Texcoord;        
    public Vector4<byte> Color;
}

public struct Vector2<T>
{
    public T x, y;
}

public struct Vector3<T>
{
    public T x, y, z;
}

public struct Vector4<T>
{
    public T x, y, z, w;
}
```

And get the pointers:

```
fixed (void* posPtr = &vertices[0].Pos.x, 
    texPtr = &vertices[0].Texcoord.x, 
    colorPtr = &vertices[0].Color.x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got some questions regarding to your answer: 1. Is the `StructLayout` flag necessary? what it does? I'm not sure about it 2. My `Vertex` consist with several structs, the position defined with `Vector2` struct, it has X and Y (float) properties, same thing goes to TexCoords. For the Color I define `Vector4b`, it is a struct that consist with 4 color properties (r g b a) with byte data type. Is it ok?

Comment: @SirusDoma If all of them are structures, this should work (even without the explicit `StructLayout` attribute). Especially using the second method getting the exact address of the first component. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I just tested the code, but it give me compilation time error. I got two errors, the one says: `Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('Vertex')` and the other one is: `Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context`  I forgot to mention that I'm using .NET 2.0, is it fine? also seems the code beg to put into `unsafe` block..

Comment: My bad, the first error occur because my `Vertex` has `struct` with generic in one of its property (for the color property, I previously use `Vector4<byte>` now I change to `Vector4b`, which serve same purpose without generic). For the second error, I use `unsafe` keyword on the function and use an extension to make it compatible on .net 2.0 (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14339534/2209893)

Comment: @SirusDoma `IntPtr.Add` is a relatively new feature (.NET 4.0). Out of curiosity, I tried using `Vector4<byte>` for color. And getting address of `&vertex[0].color.x` still worked (i'm using 4.0 however). Also you have to make sure that the `x` is an actual variable, not a getter, setter method (if you have those for the vector).

Comment: @SirusDoma, updated the answer with generics, can't help you more without the actual source and seeing what the `Vertex` struct looks like.

Comment: That's exactly I define my `Vertex`, thanks! your code working and marked as answer. It is such coincidence that I currently working similar project after i asked the question one year ago :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I able to make it work by de-interleave the `Vertex` struct (I'm not really sure if it's called "de-interleave").
However, I believe it's not best solutions for this problem. Better solutions will be highly appreciated.

Here the codes to de-interlave each attributes and upload those attributes data each frame using Vertex Arrays:

```
    Vertex[] vertices = // Fill some vertices here..

    // This is workaround that i was talking about, de-interleave attributes of Vertex Struct
    // it might be better to de-interleaving those attributes when the change has been made to vertices rather than de-interleaving them each frames.
    List<Vector2> positions = new List<Vector2>();
    foreach (Vertex v in vertices)
        positions.Add(v.position);

    List<Vector2> texCoords = new List<Vector2>();
    foreach (Vertex v in vertices)
        texCoords.Add(v.texCoords);

    List<Vector4> colors = new List<Vector4>();
    foreach (Vertex v in vertices)
        colors.Add(v.color);

    // Use attribute stride instead of Vertex stride.
    GL.VertexPointer(2, VertexPointerType.Float, Vector2.SizeInBytes, positions.ToArray());
    GL.TexCoordPointer(2, TexCoordPointerType.Float, Vector2.SizeInBytes, texCoords.ToArray());
    GL.ColorPointer(4, ColorPointerType.Float, Vector4.SizeInBytes, colors.ToArray());

    // Draw the Vertices
    GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Quads,
        0,
        vertices.length);
```