# IntPtr.operator + (IntPtr, int) cannot call operator or accessor

Tags: c#, forms, build, compiler-errors

I have looked everywhere online and I can't seem to find the particular answer that allows this to be fixed. This is literally the only error that I am getting, and I can't build the executable until this is fixed.

```
int num3 = new VAMemory(Data.processname).ReadInt32(IntPtr.op_Addition(((IEnumerable<Process>)Process.GetProcessesByName(Data.processname)).FirstOrDefault().MainModule.BaseAddress, num2));
```

Here is the error:

```
IntPtr.operator + (IntPtr, int) cannot call operator or accessor
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to all this so I have no idea how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1. use the [IntPtr.Add(IntPtr, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.add?view=netframework-4.8) method

   ```
   var baseAddress = Process
       .GetProcessesByName(Data.processname)
       .FirstOrDefault()
       .MainModule
       .BaseAddress;
   var address = IntPtr.Add(baseAddress, num2);
   var valueAtAddress = new VAMemory(Data.processname).ReadInt32(address);
   ```
2. or transform [IntPtr to Int64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866236/add-offset-to-intptr), add `num2`, and then transform it back to IntPtr